# SQL statement to Distinct results and add data in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

The skinny is I have a program (written in VB.NET) that writes data to a SQL Server database. I am know writing statements to access that data and present it to the user.

Where I am stuck is I have a `DataGridView` setup that the first column is a list of bills that the user paid.  I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT [PayTo] 
FROM Main_Bills
```

to populate this column and it works.

The next columns are each month and then the last is a total paid to date. I am not sure how to populate the remaining columns and have them show even if they are empty. What I am trying to accomplish is:

1. Show all columns even if they don't contain data.
2. Search the database for each bill paid in the month and total it for the corresponding bill.
3. Update the last column with total paid for each bill that year.

Example if the database contains:

```
Bill Paid To       Date     Amount
----------------------------------
Electric Company   8/20/15  100.00
Electric Company   8/21/15  50.00
Water Company      8/15/15  25.00
```

So the current setup does only show Electric company once in the first column which is what I want along with water company.  What I need to have happen is based on the year (this way it only displays the bills paid during the current year). I need it to add the 2 electric payments together and display in the August column with the Electric company item in column 1. Then the same with water. Obviously there are more bills then this that will be in the system.

I hope this all makes sense. Code section is below:

```
Sub SummaryTab_Fill()
Try
con = New SqlConnection(conString)
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT [PayTo] FROM Main_Bills", con)
con.Open()
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
table = New DataTable
table.Load(reader)
DGVBillSum.AutoGenerateColumns = True
DGVBillSum.RowHeadersVisible = False
DGVBillSum.DataSource = table
DGVBillSum.ColumnCount = 14
DGVBillSum.Columns(0).Name = "Paid To"
DGVBillSum.Columns(1).Name = "January"
DGVBillSum.Columns(2).Name = "February"
DGVBillSum.Columns(3).Name = "March"
DGVBillSum.Columns(4).Name = "April"
DGVBillSum.Columns(5).Name = "May"
DGVBillSum.Columns(6).Name = "June"
DGVBillSum.Columns(7).Name = "July"
DGVBillSum.Columns(8).Name = "August"
DGVBillSum.Columns(9).Name = "September"
DGVBillSum.Columns(10).Name = "October"
DGVBillSum.Columns(11).Name = "November"
DGVBillSum.Columns(12).Name = "December"
DGVBillSum.Columns(13).Name = "Total"
DGVBillSum.Sort(DGVBillSum.Columns(0), ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
DGVBillSum.Refresh()
con.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
 'I need to add my catch statement
End Try
```

Comment: What you probably want to do is do a select distinct on the bill paid to column.  Then loop through each row do a select on bill paid to to get all rows for each company. Then add the total to for each month. and put it in a temp table or another table and then select and display those results in your gridview

Comment: I was originally going to create another table and have one to populate my first column then the second to handle the math part, but I figured that would get to confusing.  I am still fairly new to writing SQL statements and VB.NET.  That is why I am writing a income and bill program for home use, to expand on what I have already learned and reach into areas we didn't cover in class.  After reading your comment, I am thinking I should first filter down the results to all bills paid in the current year.  Then use VB to filter the results of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you get all the records from the current year and aggregate them in a function.

```
Sub SummaryTab_Fill(conString As String)
    Try
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conString)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Main_Bills WHERE Date BETWEEN '{0}/1/1' AND '{0}/12/31", Date.Now.Year), con)
        con.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
        table.Load(reader)

        Dim dataSource As Datatable 
        datasource = AggregateData(table)

        DGVBillSum.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DGVBillSum.RowHeadersVisible = False
        DGVBillSum.DataSource = datasource
        DGVBillSum.ColumnCount = 14
        DGVBillSum.Columns(0).Name = "Paid To"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(1).Name = "January"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(2).Name = "February"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(3).Name = "March"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(4).Name = "April"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(5).Name = "May"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(6).Name = "June"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(7).Name = "July"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(8).Name = "August"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(9).Name = "September"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(10).Name = "October"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(11).Name = "November"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(12).Name = "December"
        DGVBillSum.Columns(13).Name = "Total"
        DGVBillSum.Sort(DGVBillSum.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        DGVBillSum.Refresh()

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
     'I need to add my catch statement
    End Try
End Sub

Function AggregateData(sqlTable As DataTable) as Datatable

    Dim table As New DataTable

    ' Creates the primary key column
    table.Columns.Add("PaidTo", GetType(String))
    table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn(){table.Columns("PaidTo")} 'This is necessary to use table.Rows.Find()
    ' Creates the months column and total
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("January"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("February"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("March"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("April"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("May"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("June"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("August"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("September"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("October"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("November"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("December"))
    table.Columns.Add(CreateMonthColumn("Total")) 
    table.Columns("Total").Expression = "January + February + March + April + May ..." 'This expression is like using SQL


    For Each row as DataRow in sqlTable.Rows

        Dim companyRow As DataRow
        companyRow = table.Rows.Find(row("PaidTo"))

        if IsNothing(companyRow) Then 'If there is no previous record of this company, create a new record
            companyRow = table.NewRow()
            companyRow("PaidTo") = row("PaidTo")
            table.Rows.Add(companyRow)
        End If 


        Dim payDate As DateTime = row("Date")
        Dim amoutValue As Double = row("Amount")
        'Let's aggregate for each month
        Select Case payDate.Date.Month
            Case 1
                   'Can't recall if this works: companyRow["January"] += amoutValue
                   companyRow("January") = ctype(companyRow("January"),double) + amoutValue

            Case 2


         End Select
    Next

    AggregateData = table

End Function

'Avoid repetition

Function CreateMonthColumn(name As String) As Datacolumn
    Dim column As DataColumn

    column = New DataColumn
    With column
       .ColumnName = name
       .DataType = GetType(Double)
       .DefaultValue = 0
       .Unique = False 
    End With

    CreateMonthColumn = column
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try later today and report back.  I will make sure to mark as answer if I get it working.

Comment: I gave this a try but there where a lot of syntax errors.  To many for me to try to fix.  I am still working at it.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you review the answer? Had the opportunity to create a vb.net project